# How to link 2 separate models in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm making a project management tool to learn Laravel.

Right now I have 2 models for Project and Task, and I have set the relationship between the two:

Project:

```
public function task()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Task::class);
}
```

Task:

```
public function project()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Project::class);
}
```

These are working fine, I can see the correct results in `php artisan tinker`, but right now I'm hard-coding which project all tasks belong to.

I have created, working, forms that create both of these things independently at the moment but I'm now sure how to link them together like a professional developer would.

The only solution I can think of, is to have a dropdown list on the `createTask` view populated with all the projects that are currently live. This doesn't feel very elegant, and doesn't feel like how a proper developer would handle it. I feel like creating a task in this sense, should be properly tied in with the project?

Comment: Any way you try to do it, the task will have to know what project it is assigned to. If you are already know this information going into the createTask view then you won't need a drop down, you simply post the project information along with the task information. You can use a hidden form, send the project uuid in the route, etc. If you don't know what project the task belongs to, then how will your code unless you allow it to be input into a form?

Comment: @NMahurin yes this is my issue, I have no experience to know a sensible way to structure my project. I am thinking perhaps a link on the `Project` view that directs to a route like `Route::get('/task/create/{projectid}', 'TaskController@create')` or something like that so I always have a project ID linked to the creation of a task

Comment: That would be a good way to do it. You'll have access to the projectid in your controller, which you can pass onto the form. If you haven't yet, look up hidden inputs. Sometimes they can be a quick way to get extra data posted. I don't use them much anymore (since you will get better at structure/routing with more experience), but they can be a start.

Comment: User interfaces are hard. There's no silver bullet on how to properly handle these things. Big companies collect tons of data before they actually decide which user interface is the most user friendly for their user base .. and even then they still get it wrong more often than not. Rule of thumb is "how would Google do this" . That's usually a good start

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're on the right path and I think its more a matter of how you want your application to work.

The approach you outlined is one way to accomplish it and would be appropriate for an "all projects" view where the app does not know what project the user is going to assign the task to.

Another option would be to create an "edit project" view that only displays information for a single project.   This time, since you know the ID of the project the task will be added to, rather than displaying a dropdown you can use a hidden form element to pass the ID.

Depending on the interface, both methods may be appropriate.